# What's Wrong With This Quantum Analogy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, frequency, discrete, thought-experiment

> "Sometimes the idea of the quantum is compared to the units we use for
>   money. A dollar can be divided into smaller units, where the cent is
>   the smallest possible unit."

A question I came across in a textbook. Given that their Planck formula is $E=nhf$, how is the analogy incorrect?

Comment: Were you able to rule out any of the three factors as key to the question?

Answer (score 1):

For example, when you are looking at the photon emitted from an electron going from energy level n=2 to n=1, the photon has a discrete energy and all photons that do this transition will have the same energy. However, if the photon passes from different energy levels (say n=3 to n=1), it will have a different energy. Both photons have discrete energies; however, they have different energy values.

In that was they are discrete, but have different values. 1 cent pieces are discrete, but all have the same value.